# Book about a young girl saved from a boat, on trial about what she knows, and ends with realization that she’s a robot

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, robots, dystopia

I vaguely remember the protagonist is saved from a boat, which lands on an island. She’s not allowed to leave and ends up in a tribunal or some other sort of trial regarding whether or not she should live or die.  She is ultimately too bright and has too many questions during the interrogation focused on trying to determine how much she knows.  It ends with a plot twist where she realizes she’s a robot and therefore can not be allowed to live.

I don’t remember the author or title but it was a quick read, and perhaps was a young adult book. The jacket had a picture of her but it only showed the back or side of her blond hair and not her face.

I read it about 4 or 5 years ago.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SF & F! How long ago did you read this story? One month ago? One year ago? Two or more years ago?

Comment: It looks like you may have lost the original user you used to create this question.  You should [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to regain control of your question. That will enable you to edit it, comment on answers, and accept the correct answer when it is posted.